# how to write a vbscript to ask for password for running the actual script....?

Tags: passwords, password-protection

I want a vbscript which can be added before a desired vbscript to ask for a password to run the desired vbscript.

For example, a script for opening the browser window is there.  I want to add password protection for running this script.  On running the whole script, first it should ask for password, and then if password is correct, it should then open the browser window.  If the password is wrong then ask for the password until it is correct.

I tried the below script to run a `.bat` file which was located at `D:\Technical\jarvis Files\close firefox.bat` in my pc, but had no successs.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

dim password

password=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","3 - Tries Left")

if password = ("---------YOUR PASSWORD HERE---------") then
    dim correct
    correct =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
    objShell.Run("-------YOUR LINK HERE--------")

Else

dim again

      again =MsgBox("Incorect Password! Do You Want To Try Again?",53,"Incorect Password!")

    If again = 4 Then
    dim password2
    password2=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","2 - Tries Left")
    if password2 = ("---------YOUR PASSWORD HERE---------") then
        dim correct2
        correct2 =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
        objShell.Run("-------YOUR LINK HERE--------")
    Else
        dim again2
        again2 =MsgBox("Incorect Password! Do You Want To Try Again?",53,"Incorect Password!")
        If again2 = 4 Then
        dim password3
        password3=InputBox("Please Enter Password:","1 - Tries Left")
        if password3 = ("---------YOUR PASSWORD HERE---------") then
            dim correct3
            correct3 =MsgBox("Correct Password!",64,"correct")
            objShell.Run("-------YOUR LINK HERE--------")
        Else
            dim again3
            again3 =MsgBox("Incorect Password! Do You Want To Try Again?",53,"Incorect Password!")
            If again3 = 4 Then

                dim incorect
                incorect =MsgBox("To many incorect passwords! Program will now lock!",16,"WARNIG!!")
                objShell.Run("-------YOUR FAIL LINK HERE--------")

                    end if

                end if

            end if

        end if

    end if

end if
```

This is just what I tried, but I want to do it the other way.  Instead of running a `.vbs` or `.bat` file with this, I want to integrate the code of that vbs script after the password prompt script so that before running the program script, the password is asked for.

Comment: I downvoted this question because you asked a similar one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001076/how-to-know-the-url-instance-of-the-webpage-in-the-browser-window-using-vbs). Please make an attempt to write this yourself. Then post your code with specific questions and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: this is not the same as the one you linked....this is about password protection of a script before it runs....for example a script runs an XYZ program...i want a ABC (password prompt) script which when added before this XYZ script, should lead to asking for password when "ABC-XYZ" script as a whole is run....

Comment: My comment from that other post still stands, though. Make an attempt yourself. Post what you've tried. Then we can point you in the right direction. You need to make *some* kind of effort. Nobody here is going to write it completely for you.

Comment: okay, thanks buddy...actually i m not a programmer, i am a doctor...i got something from internet which i tried, but it didnt work...so i tried to search some community which can help me...i thought there are plenty of users here who can help, but i dont think anybody is interested, or may be its too difficult and time consuming to write such a script that's why nobody is comming up with a solution.....

Comment: i deleted the one i got from some website as it was not working, so i cant show you what i tried....it was a script which used to open a password message box, and if entered correct password it would run a specific program....but it didnt work as it said...so i deleted it tried to ask the programmer community here....

Comment: @Bond ....if you can give me your e mail i can send you in detail what i wanna do ....this place is too small to write the whole thing....
mine is vibs_garg007@yahoo.co.in

Comment: Please post the code you found and explain why it doesn't work or why it doesn't meet your requirements. It helps to start with something.

Comment: @Bond..i have entered the script above in the description....dont know how to edit it for the page here to be displayed as a script

Answer (score 0):

The code you found is just using the `InputBox()` function to prompt the user to enter some text. In this case, the password. While you can certainly use `InputBox()` for this purpose, the text won't be obfuscated while the user is typing, which means their password will be visible to anyone looking over their shoulder.

BTW, this code isn't meant for a batch file (.BAT). It's a VBScript, which means you need to give it a .VBS extension. If you do that, then double-click it, you can see what it's doing.

See [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php) page for two ways you can prompt the user to enter a password using VBScript. One is done via the command prompt and the other uses Internet Explorer to create a login form.

Good luck.

Comment: i saved it as .vbs only....bat file i entered at ("-------YOUR LINK HERE--------")....it was the file to be run.....

Comment: never mind...i think its something too difficult to be answered by anyone here......